# Install Apps from unknown sources inside work profile in Android Lollipop 5.0.1

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, mdm, android-developer-api

Question is related to Work Profile in "***Android for work***" .
I have written a sample app that creates a managed work profile and sets itself as the **profile owner**.

I will need to push some enterprise applications through the profile owner . So when i try to install , it says "Install blocked" , Cannot install from unknown sources .

If i toggle the button (***Setting->security->Unknown Source***) on and off , settings are not getting reflected in the work profile. Is there a way to install the apps in work profile from unknown sources ?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am stuck with the same problem

Comment: I think there is no further update for unknown-source app to be installed on WorkProfile.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it could be resolved with future updates, but as of now, Android 5.0 only allows primary users to install apps from unknown sources.

Alternatively, you could install your app using `adb install` to push your app for both users.

Comment: Yes , i can install it from adb , but my requirement is to push the application to all the android clients through my profile onwer app . What if Organization needs to push more than 1 app as part of MDM . Say 1 application will be profile owner and other apps are also needed with in the profile ? Installing from work profile Playstore is only option  ?