# Set work profile using wso2 agent app android

Tags: wso2-iot

I had follow the below instruction from offical wso2 site https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM220/Data+Containerization+for+Android+Device

But after completed the setup work profile and unstall the agent app from personal profile.

And I have checked my work profile there is no agent app is in accounts page. Please let me know if any solution.

Comment: What is the device you are using to create a work profile? Does it have stock OS or a customised OS?

Comment: I'm tested using lava mobile. could you tell which mobile I have to test? Is it work in android emulator?

Comment: Please test with a device that has an OS without customizations. E.g a Nexus device. The emulator does not work as well because the it doesn't support mobile encryption feature.

Comment: Thankyou Bro I will try.. I more doubt in production I got error while xml parshing using -DworkerNode and it's work good in first time run then if i stop the server and runs once again I faced the parshing issue.. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: So data containerisation only worked on Nexes, Moto and without OS customised devices only uh bro?

Comment: It does not depend on the device type. But if the vendor has customised the features that affect the work-profile generation then it will not work.

Comment: Try to create a work profile using Google Device Policy App in the lava mobile device and see whether it gets successful.

Comment: Ok, Thankyou bro.. Is there any solution for the error while xml parshing when start server using -DworkerNode in production?

Comment: Hi @mds I have checked work profile using Moto 2g device and android agent app version 2.0. but I have faced same problem. I have checked in settings>account it shows workprofile isn't  available yet. So please let me know what step I have missed?

Comment: Try to create a work profile using Google Device Policy App and see if it successes?

Comment: No bro.. I haven't try yet. But moto 2g is not a customised OS. then why isn't work?

Comment: Hi Bro, I tested work profile using device policy in lava device which i have tested first. It works good. then why wso2 didn't create the work profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably occurs due to an [issue](https://wso2.org/jira/projects/EMM/issues/EMM-1807) in the android agent. To fix it, you can edit the following line and set the `android:exported` to `true`.

https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/master/modules/mobile-agents/android/client/client/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L99

```
<receiver
        android:name=".services.AgentDeviceAdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
        android:exported="true">
```

Once you have done this, you can re-build the agent application and then you will be able to generate the work profile successfully. Fix for this issue should be available with the next release.

Comment: Bro, Now work profile works fine..but there is issue when install the enterprise app via emm store. Please refer the [Screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzr64jbeuob9xir/app_install.png?dl=0). and also everytime open the apps asks credentials. So please let me know why it happens?

Comment: Seems like you haven't allowed app installations from unknown sources. This is an android configuration. You need to allow that from Settings > Security

Comment: Ya..I already checked it's enabled bro. And also everytime I opened the app it asks credentials..

Comment: Please refer the screens. [screen1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1d9s8i6z1yoo8bj/admin.png?dl=0) [screen2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4hkzebzn02ctq3/security.png?dl=0)

Comment: @mdawa Is there any solution? did you refer the above screenshot?

Comment: Hi bro, I think this is the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253323/install-apps-from-unknown-sources-inside-work-profile-in-android-lollipop-5-0-1